# how do I automatically adjust textSize in android?

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I am writing an app, in which part of it displays a line of text. there are certain scenarios where that line of text will take up more than one line. the problem is that I only want it to take up one line, and when I set it up either in java or in xml to only take up one line, the text is cut off. how would I make it so that it automatically adjusts the font size of the text so that it will only take up one line without being cut off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use proportions along with [Paint.measureText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29):

(text size / measureText width) = (perfectSize / screenWidth)

Solving for the perfect text size:

```
perfectSize = (text size / measureText width) * screenWidth;
```

You can find the screen width with `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()` from the [Display](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html) class.

Turned it into a math problem!

Comment: I just tried this, and what happened was, every time, the text ends up so small, that I can't even see it.

Comment: Because of th wrong function, it should be modify as perfectSize = (text size / measureText width) * screenWidth;

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too hard to do if you use [Paint#measureText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.String%29).

Basically you would start with a font height smaller than the height of your `TextView` and then iterate (or do a binary search) through fonts of varying sizes until you find one that measures to smaller than the width of your `TextView`.

It requires some implementation, as there is no "automatic" way provided by the framework.